# Select the after pseudo element of the li first child

Tags: css

I am attempting to target the first list item's pseudo element ":after". All of the other li's have dropdowns and so they have a little arrow after the text. Is there any way to target the pseudo of a pseudo? I only resort to this becuase it's a wordpress menu and I'm unsure of how to add a class to that specific li. So far I have tried:

```
#menu-primary-menu>li>a:first-child:after{
//some css
}
```

Thanks in advance for your advice!

Comment: When you say "the li first child", do you mean "the li that is the first child", or "the li's first child" (with a possessive)?

Comment: I actually just figured it out. I needed the first li and to target the a:after inside of it

Answer (score 0):

Not long after posting this I figured it out. I had to target the first li (li:first-child) and then the after element of the link (a:after) and so the path required was:

```
#menu-primary-menu li:first-child a:after
```

Apologies for asking a question and then just answering it myself. I'm going to leave it here in case anyone else stumbles accross.